# Watson Conversation System date entity dateformat changes for '/' vs '-'

Tags: watson-conversation, watson

Watson Conversation System Entity sys-date is giving different results if I change '/' with '-'

As per [documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/system-entities.html#sys-datetime):

> Note: - For English locale only, the default system behavior for date
>   input is MM/DD/YYYY. This will change to DD/MM/YYYY only if the first
>   two numbers are greater than 12. The value stored will still be in the
>   format "yyyy-MM-dd".

However when i am testing with '-' its taking DD/MM/YYYY

`12/01/2017` => `2017-12-01` (Correct)

`12-01-2017` => `2017-01-12` (incorrect)

Ideally Watson should interpret both as same dates as this '/', '-' will confuse the users. Is there anyway to make it interpret as same dates.
[Date Sample Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCMhk.png)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is not possible to change the way the dates are interpreted in the shared version of IBM Watson Conversation Service (WCS). The date which you labeled as incorrect is actually correct when looking at [ISO date formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date#Standards).

What you could do for your customization issue is to assess the metadata provided by WCS. You have access to the location information about where in a string the data was detected and also what exactly the user typed. You could use that to interpret date values in the desired form.